# Disable selecting Query Table on Power Query Refresh

Tags: excel, vba, selection, powerquery, listobject

I have written the following code in a Worksheet module, to refresh a Power Query table, that once refreshed, should allow Cell B3 to get selected and add a dropdown there using the unique values from the 1st column of the table. I am using the `QueryTable_AfterRefresh()` method to indicate whether the `Query refresh completed successfully`.

```
Private WithEvents table As Excel.QueryTable

Private Sub table_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until Success
    Me.Cells(3, "B").Select
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim Rng As Range, Rng1, V, Dict As Object, Frm As String

Set Rng = Me.Cells(3, "B")
Set table = Me.ListObjects("_Rpt4").QueryTable
Set Rng1 = table.ListObject.ListColumns("Answers").DataBodyRange

Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each V In Rng1.Cells
    On Error Resume Next
    Dict.Add Key:=CStr(V.Value), Item:=CStr(V.Value)
    On Error GoTo 0
Next V

Frm = Join(Dict.Keys, ",")

If Target.Address = "$D$3" Then
    With table
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    
    DoEvents
    AddDataValidation Rng:=Rng, sFormula:=Frm
    
ElseIf Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
    If Target.Value2 <> "" Then
        table.ListObject.Range.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value2
        table.ListObject.ShowAutoFilterDropDown = False
    ElseIf Target.Value2 = "" Then
        table.ListObject.Range.AutoFilter field:=1
        table.ListObject.ShowAutoFilterDropDown = False
    End If
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Sub AddDataValidation(Rng As Range, sFormula As String)
Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Rng.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=sFormula
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The code works fine, however, the table still gets highlighted (selected) and the selection doesn't move to the B3 cell (it does, only for a short time).

Is there an option or a way to disable the Power Query table getting selected once the query gets successfully refreshed?

Comment: Possible that you need to disable events (`Application.EnableEvents=False`) before you update the Query table, and enable them after you select B3 (`Application.EnableEvents=True`).

Comment: you mean in the `table_AfterRefresh` procedure? Doesnt work! Table still getting highlighted.

Comment: Disable it in the worksheet change event before you update the query table. Re-enable it after you selected B3 in the after refresh event

Comment: @RonRosenfeld can you demonstrate with an example what you meant?

Comment: Which line of code refreshes your query table?  Disable events somewhere before that line of code.  Which line of code selects `B3`?  Re-enable events after that line of code.

Comment: `.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False`

Comment: Of course, that might not work since it might also inhibit the `after-refresh` event.  So you may need to disable right after the refresh event triggers, and re-enable after selecting B3.

Comment: it still didnt work and the table still got selected instead of the dropdown cell B3.

Comment: Sorry very confused. Could you show me with my above code where exactly the lines should go? ...And why in the 1st place the table should get highlighted? there should be some setting to avoid the table selection...

Comment: I don't have time to set up a model.  But I'm guessing the problem is that events are being triggered when you don't want them to be.  I'll try to set something up later today.

Comment: Also, whenever I've set up an event for something like that, I've always done it within a class module.  Are you sure your `table_AfterRefresh` code is doing what you want?

Comment: It is a Worksheet module and it does allow the cell B3 to get selected, but immediately after that the table gets selected. I want to disable this table selection. Is this a default  power query refresh behaviour?

Comment: Yes, but does it actually detect the event and wait for the query to be refreshed before continuing?

Comment: In trying to model your selection, I note that your `AddDataValidation` function or sub code is not included. Can't mimic your problem without it.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld added the Data validation code.

Comment: Can you upload a sample workbook, with sensitive data removes, that demonstrates the problem? You can upload to some hosting site, like OneDrive, DropBox, etc; and then post a link here.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld sorry for the late reply, but was too busy. Here is a [sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wWCh_ymYSRvH8jFQl-0r1A7sccMcnhUl/view?usp=sharing) for your perusal. The issue is to remove the table highlighting.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The table does not get highlighted on the sample file you sent me.  If I select the Update button, C3 is the cell selected.

Comment: Is there some setting is Excel that turns selection on? I see this behavior all the time. I am using 64 bit Excel 2016 Pro edition.

Comment: I see it when I refresh a Power Query query manually.  I do not see it in the workbook you provided. I am not aware of a setting to control this.  I have 32 bit Office 365.

Comment: Strange. It happens on both ways viz., via code or manually...and i thought this was the default behaviour. I just repaired my office, but still the same behaviour. :-(